# Python: How to handle a corrupted gzip file in reading multiple files

Tags: python, file, gzip, readline

I am reading a large set of `gzip` files. When I tried the below code, the process cannot be finished because some of files are corrupted. Python can open those corrupted files, but the process is interrupted due to errors in certain lines in those files.

```
    for file in files:
        try:
            fin=gzip.open(file,'rb')
        except:
            continue
        
        for line in fin:
            try:
                temp=line.decode().split(",")
                a,b,c,d=temp[0],int(temp[1]),int(temp[2]),int(temp[3])
            except:
                continue
```

But the program stops because of the following error.
What is the best way to process a corrupted `gzip` file?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):---------------------------| 9.0% Complete
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 374, in readline
    return self._buffer.readline(size)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 463, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/gzip.py", line 411, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'rv')
```

I have modified the code as below, and seems like running well, but not sure if this is the best way to handle such cases.
Because for certain cases, the program seems not terminate (I need to test more).

```
    for file in files:
        try:
            fin=gzip.open(file,'rb')
        except:
            continue
        
        line=True
        while line:
            try:
                line=fin.readline()
            except:
                continue
            try:
                temp=line.decode().split(",")
                a,b,c,d=temp[0],int(temp[1]),int(temp[2]),int(temp[3])
            except:
                continue
```

Comment: you could at least use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see when there is the problem. You could also count exception and exit this loop after ie. 3 exceptions.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about reading a corrupted gzip file. You seem to be asking how to read multiple files and gracefully handle corrupted gzip files. Can you please edit your title to reflect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iteration over the file is outside of any `try`... `except`, so an exception raised here will terminate the program.  If you have a single try...except around the whole thing, then it should work:

```
    for file in files:
        try:
            with gzip.open(file,'rb') as fin:
                for line in fin:
                    temp = line.decode().split(",")
                    a,b,c,d = temp[0], int(temp[1]), int(temp[2]), int(temp[3])
        except (OSError, ValueError):
            continue
```

Note also:

- Only catching the specific exceptions that we would expect to occur with a bad file, not other things that should still terminate the program (e.g. `KeyboardInterrupt`). A bare `except:` is usually a bad idea.
- It is better to use a `with` construct with `gzip.open`

Comment: `except (OSError, ValueError):` Parenthesis are necessary here to avoid a syntax error

Comment: @SurpriseDog Thanks - now edited. (Looks like that was python 2 syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

I have splitted the file processing part into a separate function to handles exceptional cases during processing each file.

```
def proc_file(file):
    try:
        fin=gzip.open(file,'rb')
    except:
        return
        
    err_cnt=0

    while err_cnt<10:
        try:
            line=fin.readline()
        except:
            err_cnt+=1
            continue
        if not line:
            err_cnt+=1
            continue
        try:
            temp=line.decode().split(",")
            a,b,c,d=temp[0],int(temp[1]),int(temp[2]),int(temp[3])
        except:
            continue
    return processed_value

for file in files:

    result=[]
    try:
        value=proc_file(file)
    except:
        continue
    
    result.append(value)
```